# Read Config From Another Project - Log4Net ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, log4net

I am trying to write a class library that uses `log4net` that looks something like this:

```
public class Logging
{
    private ILog log4netLogger = null;

    public Logging(Type type)
    {
        XmlDocument log4netConfig = new XmlDocument();
        log4netConfig.Load(File.OpenRead("log4net.config"));

        var repo = LogManager.CreateRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), typeof(log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy));

        XmlConfigurator.Configure(repo, log4netConfig["log4net"]);

        log4netLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(type);
    }

    public void Debug(string message)
    {
        log4netLogger(message);
    }

    public void Info(string message)
    {
        log4netLogger(message);
    }
}
```

However, the `xml` configuration is in my test console app in `C:\....\TestLogging\TestLog4Net\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1`.  I actually started with this console app to test `log4net` but I have moved all my code from the `main` method of `Program.cs` to the `Logging.cs` constructor, but I think the `LogManager` will not be able to find this now.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Just pass the correct full path instead of a relative path. Better yet, put the config file in a common folder

Comment: You can share files between projects in a solution. In `Add > Existing Item` select `Add As Link` from the button menu instead of clicking `Add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible. To use the log4net in the class library, you have to install the [log4net package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore/) in the class library, then, you could add the class library reference in the console application and use the class library method. But, as you said, the `log4net.config` file should be in the console application netcoreapp3.1 folder, otherwise, the class library will not find the `log4net.config` file:

[image]

Comment: Yes strangely my code just works as long as you have the `log4net.config` in the build dir like in your screen shot for the console app.  What I am confused about is how does the `XmlDocument` code know where exactly to get the config from.  The reason I ask is to test I deliberately took the config out of the build dir and it threw an exception saying it couldn't find the config from path `TestConsoleApp\bin\Debug\....` Is this because the `log4net.config` is referenced in my console app `csproj`?

Comment: After adding the Class library in the Console app, you can see that the Class library's .dll file and the Console app's .exe file are located in the ".netcoreapp3.1" folder, when running the Console app, the default current directory path is the "C:\....\TestLogging\TestLog4Net\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1" folder, you can use the `string defaultsPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); if File.Exists(defaultsPath + "\\log4net.config")) { } ' to check it in the `Main` method. If you want to change the log4net.config file location, you have to change the path in the File.OpenRead() method.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense now; however, I am now trying to instantiate my `Logger.cs` class from my `xUnit` test project and now the default path is the `bin\debug\...` of the test build dir.  I could copy the `log4net.config` to the Test project but this seems to be a bit messy.  Is there a way I can tell the `Logger.cs` to always look in the console app build dir for the `log4net.config`?